# dynamic user control in a winform question

Tags: winforms, user-controls

I have a user control that I'm adding at runtime to a panel. There is an add button to keep adding the same user control to the panel. My question is what is the best way to clear the user controls out (properly disposing of them) when you save the form or clear the form? I want to delete all additional user controls that were added from the add button and clear the first one.

Comment: Code or specific example please..

Comment: I was just wanting a "best practice". But either of those 2 will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Control.ControlCollection.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove.aspx) method will do the trick.  Run this on your user controls' container.

For example, if your user control's Type is `YourUserControlType` and the container from which you want to remove all instances of your user control is a Panel called `panel1`, this code should work:

```
var controlList = new List<YourUserControlType>(panel1.Controls.OfType<YourUserControlType>());
controlList.ForEach(c => {
    panel1.Controls.Remove(c);
});
```

**EDIT:**  for .NET 2.0+

```
List<YourUserControlType> controlList = new List<YourUserControlType>();
for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++) {
    YourUserControlType uc = panel1.Controls[i] as YourUserControlType;
    if (uc != null) {
        controlList.Add(uc);
    }
}

foreach (YourUserControlType uc in controlList) {
    panel1.Controls.Remove(uc);
}
```

Notice in both versions we're avoiding removing controls from the controls collection as we're iterating through that collection.  Unless you're careful, removing items from the collection as you're iterating through can causes problems.

Comment: My target framework is 2.0. Will something similar work in 2.0? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Does this.panel1.Controls.Clear(); do the same thing?

Comment: @user766595 `this.panel1.Controls.Clear(); ` will remove _all_ controls in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give a lot of specific details on how you add those controls at runtime, I'll assume that you instantiate them (using new), and then add them to the forms' Controls collection.

One way to delete those runtime added controls would be to also add them to a List, and when you need to delete all the runtime controls, simply iterate over the List, calling MyForm.Controls.Remove(theControl) for each Control in the List. Finish by calling Clear() on the List.

Cheers